# Unable to setup ssl with express node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

I have set up my server.js file like this:

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server2.crt'),
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('./csr.pem'),
};

var server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

The cert and key are self signed using:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server2.crt
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem
```

Doesn't matter what I do, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:85:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:776:25)
    at new Server (https.js:27:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:48:10)
```

I looked at other SO answers which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your sslOptions look [incorrect](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options). Instead use key and cert:

```
key: fs.readFileSync( "./key.pem" ),
cert: fs.readFileSync( "./server2.crt" )
```